# Is There a Way to Represent Distance Between Arrays on a 2d Graph?

Tags: python, arrays, distance, measure

I am writing a program for evolutionary research in python. The output of my program is a bunch of neural nets (graphs of fixed size/structure).

For all intents and purposes, the neural nets can be simply represented by an array of connection weights in some fixed order.

I would like to be able to somehow represent neural nets visually to show whether the output of my program converges into a similar type of net or many different clusters.

For instance, imagine 50 arrays that look like this:

```
[.5, -.25, 2.31, -3.2, 1, .88 ...etc ]
```

I would like to somehow plot these so it is visually evidence which arrays of similar to each other.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the connectivity information? Or just the pairwise weights? Seems you could either make a graph where all nodes connect to each other, and have the line weight partially transparent with thickness proportional to the score, or with the line lengths proportional. Some graphing library examples are [here](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/creating_network_graphs_with_python)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your neural networks are seeded with random values, it is unlikely that there will be any meaningful relationship between the ordered list of weights. You could check how functionally similar they are by comparing their outputs for a large set of inputs.

If you really want to compare the weights, you could plot a 2D histogram of weight index vs network vs weight value. Using pyROOT:

```
from pyROOT import TH2D
z_min, z_max = #suitable range for weight values
h = TH2D("h", "h", 50, -0.5, 49.5, n_weights, -0.5, n_weights-0.5, 100, z_min, z_max)
for i_network in range(50):
    for i_weight in range(n_weights):
        h.Fill(i_network, i_weight, networks[i_network][i_weight]

h.Draw("colz")
```

here rows with similar colours would indicate consistent weight values across the networks.

Comment: To clarify, I am comparing neural nets after they have been trained through both back propagation and an evolutionary algorithm. Even though they are seeded with random values, they might converge on very similar connection weights